# Why does an iterative approximation algorithm sometime have fewer iterations despite larger input values?

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop, square-root, bisection

[image]
Why does my iterative approximation loop get executed fewer times when executed for 24690 than 12345 which is half the size?

I am using a bisection algorithm or bisecting search.  Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on [how your bisection loop is terminated](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDMQFjAD&url=http://www.emis.de/journals/NSJOM/Papers/27_1/NSJOM_27_1_019_026.pdf&ei=WBVgVaHJDoG2sQWyroHwDA&usg=AFQjCNGXe3IEILs_DaLnKnxGZ9y3GS94Xg&sig2=IoZugJtileb9bsPZUT3ZpA).  The [divide-and-average method](https://web.archive.org/web/20180314015232/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52623.html) (also called [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)) can be iterated a fixed number of times (obviously not in your case) or it can go until the successive differences are within some tolerance.  In the latter case, the number of iterations doesn't depend on size, it depends on the remainders of the divisions (i.e. how close the initial guesses are).

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: but if we think of an algorithm in finding the sqrt of 24690 it will first get to half which is 12345 and then it will execute same no. of loops 26 loops which is showing in pic.so 24690 should take 27 times loop.

Comment: @AkshatPatni Try printing-out the intermediate values in your loop.  You mental model doesn't seem to match what the code is doing.  The divide-and-average method will average ``(1 + 12345) / 2`` which is not exactly half of ``(1 + 24690)``.  Also, it matters whether the convergences tolerance is fixed or a ratio.   Without you posting code or you looking at the intermediate values, it is hard to help you see what is going on.  You don't have a programming problem, it seems to be an issue understanding the math.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simple example of 4 and 8

4/2 =2 ( 2*2=4) therefore we get the answer in 1 iteration
8/2 =4 (4*4=16) therefore you will do more than 1 iteration

**Number of steps is not linear to input value**